# Symfony 4 Tests error

Tags: php, symfony, testing

When I run tests I have an error

[image]

But if I run it again without anything, error has gone

[image]

DATABASE_URL_ADM configured in .env , seems like symfony can't read file before runing test, because if I add sleep(3), then test running after 3 sec without error from the first time. Maybe I missed something important.

Test code:

```
 public function testAdvertisement()
 {
    $res = $this->req('custom/advertisement');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $res->getStatusCode());
 }
```

Req method is:

```
 public function req($uri, $method = 'GET', $params = [])
 {
    $parameters = ['token' => $this->getToken($this->tokenUsername)];

    if ($method === 'GET' && !empty($params)) {
        $parameters = array_merge($parameters, $params);
    }

    $query = http_build_query($parameters);

    if ($pos = strpos($uri, "?")) {
        $uri = substr($uri, 0, $pos);
    }

    if (!$this->custom) {
        $uri = $this->baseUri . $uri;
    }

    $this->custom = false;

    return $this->guzzle->request(
        $method,
        '/v1/' . $uri . '?' . $query . '&_format=json',
        [\GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => $params]);
 }
```

Comment: Could you paste here test code?

Comment: Have added test code. But I think it's not a point. Because I always have this problem with the first test, when I run for sample hundred of tests, another 99 goes well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to dublicate your

> .env

config variables into

> phpunit.xml

like

```
<env name="DATABASE_URL_ADM" value="mysql://dev:devpass@site.com:3306/db" />
```